# An error when I add $state service to my references in angularjs module

Tags: angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing, angular-services

I have some problems to use `$state` service on my tutorial project.

Here is my module and config definition:

```
(function () {
"use strict";
angular.module("gameManagement", ["ui.router", "ngAnimate", "ngResource"])

    .config(["$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider","$state", function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterPorvider,$state) {
        $urlRouterPorvider.otherwise("/game/MultiStepForm/step1");
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/game/Home");
        $stateProvider
            .state("Home", {
                url: "/game/Home",
                templateUrl: "/app/game/GameView.html",
                controller: "GameController",
                controllerAs: "vm"
            });

        $stateProvider
            .state("Log", {
                url: "/Game/Log",
                templateUrl: "/app/Log/GameLogView.html",
                controller: "GameLogController",
                controllerAs: "vm"

                onEnter: function () {
                    $state.go("MultiStepForm");
                }
            });

        $stateProvider
        .state("MultiStepForm.view", {
            url: "/Game/MultiStepFormView",
            templateUrl: "/app/MultiStepForm/MultiStepFormView.html",
            controller: "MultiStepFormViewController",
            controllerAs: "MultiStepViewLogic"
        })

        $stateProvider
    .state("MultiStepForm.Edit", {
        url: "/Game/MultiStepFormEdit",
        templateUrl: "/app/MultiStepFormEdit/MultiStepForm.html",
        controller: "MultiStepFormEditController",
        controllerAs: "MultiStepEditLogic"
    })
    }]);
})();
```

I want to use this row:

```
$state.go();
```

for this purpose I add **$state** service to references but, when I add to

references the `$state` service I start to get this error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module sensorManagement due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $state
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.2/$injector/unpr?p0=%24state
...
```

Any idea why I get the error above? What am I missing?

Comment: As @Pankaj Parkar mentions below in an answer `$state` wont be available in the `config` phase however the `onEnter`/`onExit` has access to all of the resolved dependencies. To that point, are you trying to use the `$state` inside of the `onEnter` and expecting the injection into the `.config` to handle this resolution?

Comment: @Matt so I do not need injection If I use onEnter/onExit ?

Comment: That will depend on the context; you will have to inject the `$state` service still but you would have to do it the area in which you use it. For example if you resolve the `$state` service in what appears to be the `"Log"` state then your `onEnter`/`onExit` for that state would have access to it and the code above should do what you would expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are missing a resolution in your state. You could try something like this:

```
$stateProvider
    .state("Log", {
        url: "/Game/Log",
        templateUrl: "/app/Log/GameLogView.html",
        controller: "GameLogController",
        controllerAs: "vm",
        resolve: {$state: '$state'},
        onEnter: function ($state) {
            $state.go("MultiStepForm");
        }
});
```

See the [documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki) for more information on how the `onEnter` and `onExit` callbacks work. Basically the above question doesn't inject the `$state` service correctly and thus, is unable to transition state(s) due to the callback lacking access to `$state`.

You will also want to remove the injection into the config:

```
.config(["$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider", function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
```

Comment: I tried your solution but now I get this error:
TypeError: Cannot read property '@' of null

Comment: @Michael I suspect that is not related to anything in the code mentioned above. Outside of some typo's in the question (E.G. `$urlRouterPorvider`) there are probably other issues at hand that I cannot see from here. But to answer the question, this answer would give your `onEnter` access to `$state`

Answer (score 2):

You could only access provider inside config phase of angular, `$state` dependency won't be available inside that phase because `$state` is `provider`, and you are already accessing it inside config function by appending `Provider` prefix like `$stateProvider`.

If you aim is to redirect the route then you could use `$state` dependency in run block. Do use `$state.go` from there

```
app.run(function($state){
    $state.go('somestate')
})
```

Comment: after state loaded I want to activate another state.Any idea how can I implement it?

Comment: @Michael I didn't get you..about which state you are talking about?